# How to write a Encodingfilter configuration without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

In my project, the Encodingfilter is written in the WEB.XML. But I want to write it without WEB.XML, i want write in just java class.

Encodingfilter in my WEB.XML
How can you write it in JAVA class without WEB.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Encoding filter I correctly wrote?

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size}")

    private int maxFileSize;

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size}")

    private int maxRequestSize;

    @Autowired

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{HibernateConfig.class/*, SecurityConfig.class*/};

    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};

    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{filter};
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are importing the wrong `Filter` in your `ServletInitializer`. That is also what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`:

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    //...

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{filter};
    }
}
```

Comment: @anna9999 Why don't you just test it?